# Preventing concurrent requests to same resource in client application

Tags: c#, caching, concurrent-programming

I have a client .NET application which consumes web services using WCF. Service calls are executed concurrently and can requests the same resource.

How should I go about keeping multiple resource requests from being originated?

What I have tried:
In the client side service which makes calls to the backend, I am using a ConcurrentDictionary to cache requests, unfortunately this does not keep requests to the same resource from being made, only duplicated cache items from being added twice to the dictionary. I thought about queuing similar request and responding to them after requests which made it through return. How would that fare? I am trying not to reinvent the wheel but I would think this problem should be fairly common.

I would like to avoid using a lock to serialize all possible requests to resources since the backend servers I am trying to access use a load balancer for performance and I would like to take advantage of it.

What I cannot do: Implement server-side caching (I do not have access to it) or mess with WCF settings. 
Thanks for any help/suggestions.

NOTE: I have search the site for possible duplicates but can't find any which address my problem.

Comment: Why dont use lock on the resource

Comment: The resource in on an offsite server which I does not belong to us.

Comment: I dont really know your real case situation...One thing I can propose is on your service Agent(proxy) call to the service, make sure it is sequential(synchronous call), that means until the first request is finished, the second request will be waiting in a queue, immediately the first finishes, u make the second request

Comment: Should I keep separate queues for each different resource access? One of the reason I was trying to avoid serializing calls was to be able to take advantage of the load balancer the server side is making use of

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253903/how-to-use-lazy-to-handle-concurrent-request#34254303