# How to use Lazy to handle concurrent request?

Tags: c#

I'm new in C# and trying to understand how to work with `Lazy`.

I need to handle concurrent request by waiting the result of an already running operation. Requests for data may come in simultaneously with same/different credentials.

For each unique set of credentials there can be at most one GetDataInternal call in progress, with the result from that one call returned to all queued waiters when it is ready

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Credential, Lazy<Data>> Cache
= new ConcurrentDictionary<Credential, Lazy<Data>>();

public Data GetData(Credential credential)
{
    // This instance will be thrown away if a cached
    // value with our "credential" key already exists.
    Lazy<Data> newLazy = new Lazy<Data>(
        () => GetDataInternal(credential),
        LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication
    );

    Lazy<Data> lazy = Cache.GetOrAdd(credential, newLazy);
    bool added = ReferenceEquals(newLazy, lazy); // If true, we won the race.
    Data data;

    try
    {
       // Wait for the GetDataInternal call to complete.
       data = lazy.Value;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Only the thread which created the cache value
        // is allowed to remove it, to prevent races.
        if (added) {
            Cache.TryRemove(credential, out lazy);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Is that right way to use `Lazy` or my code is not safe?

---

**Update:**

Is it good idea to start using `MemoryCache` instead of `ConcurrentDictionary`? If yes, how to create a key value, because it's a `string` inside `MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is correct. This is a standard pattern (except for the removal) and it's a really good cache because it prevents cache stampeding.

I'm not sure you want to remove from the cache when the computation is done because the computation will be redone over and over that way. If you don't need the removal you can simplify the code by basically deleting the second half.

Note, that `Lazy` has a problem in the case of an exception: The exception is stored and the factory will never be re-executed. The problem persists forever (until a human restarts the app). In my mind this makes `Lazy` completely unsuitable for production use in most cases.

This means that a transient error such as a network issue can render the app unavailable permanently.

Comment: So, when I got `lazy` I just can return `lazy.Value` ? And do not remove from the cache

Comment: If you use `PublicationOnly`, you might not get thread-safety on `valueFactory`, but exceptions wont be cached.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, but that does not prevent double execution which he seems to want and suffers from cache stampeding.

Comment: Interesting decision to cache the exception, I find that a bit peculiar.

Comment: It is horrible. The class is, alas, unusable and you need to write your own. Somewhere there was a Connect or Github issue for that but I could not find it.

Comment: @usr If I have two request with identical `credential` how many times `GetCurrentInternal` will be executed and why?

Comment: Perhaps opening an issue on GitHub would be a good idea. Although I doubt this will change, as it will be a breaking change (albeit a good one).

Comment: @ipetr once, I assume that is your intention.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov they already decided against the breaking change. My next idea would be to make a new execution mode. That's compatible and a reasonably small burden. Care to open an issue for that?

Comment: @usr But can you explain why? As I said I'm new in C# and Lazy :(

Comment: @usr Perhaps a pull request would even be better.

Comment: Only one Lazy instance will ever be returned from GetOrAdd. Some might be created and discarded, but there's only one winner. Since you are using ExecutionAndPublication mode there will be at most one factory invocation.

Comment: @usr How to be without remove from the cache? If I have some request with `credential-> data`, and after 10 minutes my data on the disk will be changed, so I initiate another request to collect new data, but with the same credential. If I dont do remove I get same old data. Am I right?

Comment: I guess you should start a 10min timer and remove from the cache after that time.

Comment: @usr If I have a timer in constructor: `_dataUpdateTimer = new Timer(GetData, null, TimeSpan.Zero, _dataUpdateInterval);`
and method 
`private void GetData(object state) { var data = GetData(credentials); ...}` 

how do I know `credentials`?

Comment: I think that timer should simply remove from the cache and the next request will provide the credentials and execute the factory again. If you don't like that you can do `new Timer(() => GetData(credentials))`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is directed to the updated part of the original question. See [@usr answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34254303/1870803) regarding thread-safety with `Lazy<T>` and the potential pitfalls.

---

> I would like to know how to avoid using `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and start
>   using MemoryCache? How to implement
>   `MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting()`?

If you're looking for a cache which has a mechanism for auto expiry, then `MemoryCache` is a good choice if you don't want to implement the mechanics yourself.

In order to utilize `MemoryCache` which forces a string representation for a key, you'll need to create a unique string representation of a credential, perhaps a given user id or a unique username?

If you can, you can create an override of `ToString` which represents your unique identifier or simply use the said property, and utilize `MemoryCache` like this:

```
public class Credential
{
    public Credential(int userId)
    {
        UserId = userId;
    }

    public int UserId { get; private set; }
}
```

And now your method will look like this:

```
private const EvictionIntervalMinutes = 10;
public Data GetData(Credential credential)
{
    Lazy<Data> newLazy = new Lazy<Data>(
        () => GetDataInternal(credential), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    CacheItemPolicy evictionPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
    { 
        AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(EvictionIntervalMinutes)
    };

    var result = MemoryCache.Default.AddOrGetExisting(
        new CacheItem(credential.UserId.ToString(), newLazy), evictionPolicy);

    return result != null ? ((Lazy<Data>)result.Value).Value : newLazy.Value;
}
```

`MemoryCache` provides you with a thread-safe implementation, this means that two threads accessing `AddOrGetExisting` will only cause a single cache item to be added or retrieved. Further, `Lazy<T>` with `ExecutionAndPublication` guarantess only a single unique invocation of the factory method.

Comment: Using `ConccurentDictionary` looks more simpler. For me its a little bit difficult to understand why we need to do `.Value` two times, for example.

Comment: Maybe we can use another constructor?           `private static string GetKey(Credentials credentials)
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}_{1}", typeof(Data).Name, credentials);
        }`

Comment: My tests fails with `NullReferencreException` inside `return lazy.Value`, because lazy == null

Comment: @ipetr You have to call `Value` two times because one is from `CacheItem` and the other is for `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: @ipetr Are you not initializing the lazy properly?

Comment: `var result` just contain `Key` its a credential string, but `RegionName` and `Value` == null

Comment: Yes, I initialize it properly

Comment: @ipetr I fixed the code. Apparently, `AddOrGetExisting` returns `null` if the item doesn't exist.

Comment: How to be if I don't have `UserId` property?

Comment: @ipetr Which unique identifier does the `Credential` class have?

Comment: I don't have such unique identifier. The cache items are added with keys `credentials.ToString()` and it is important for this method to return the same value for Credentials objects having the same credential values, and distinct values for Credentials instances with different credential values.

Comment: @ipetr Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99045/discussion-between-yuval-itzchakov-and-ipetr).